# Merging 2 regex that allow only English and Arabic characters

Tags: java, android, regex

I have a string and I want to remove any other character such as (0..9!@#$%^&*()_., ...) and keep only alphabetic characters.

After looking up and doing some tests, I got 2 regexes formats:

```java
String str = "123hello!#$% مرحبا. ok";
str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
str = str.replaceAll("\\P{InArabic}+", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

This should return "hello مرحبا ok".

But of course, this will return an empty string because we're removing any non-Latin characters in the first regex then we remove any non-Arabic characters in the second regex.

My question is, how can I merge these 2 regexes in one to keep only Arabic and English characters only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lowercase p since negation is handled with ^ and no quantifier is needed (but wouldn't hurt) since using `replaceAll`:

```
String str = "123hello!#$% مرحبا. ok";
str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z \\p{InArabic}]", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

Prints:

```
hello مرحبا ok
```

Note based on your expected results you want spaces included so a space is in the character list.

Comment: It works very well, I appreciate the explanation as well.

Comment: @Regex You could even take it a step farther and use `replaceAll("[^ \\p{L}]", "")` to replace all characters other than letters and spaces.

Comment: @VGR it seems like your code works as well, can you explain why it works for both languages if possible? I mean what does it do exactly?

Comment: @Regex As [the javadoc for Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ucc) explains, `\\p{L}` refers to a [general category](http://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#General_Category_Values) as defined by the Unicode specification.  The `L` category refers to all letters in all languages.  So, `[^ \\p{L{]` means any character which is neither a space nor a letter.

Comment: Your solution seems to be a better approach, but in my case I only want Arabic and Latin characters. However, you can edit this answer with your approach for future comers.